# Чем плох динамический Criterial Builder

Tags: jpa, criteriabuilder, dynamic, varargs

в проекте есть обращения в базу для этого создал такой метод:

```
public <E, T, X> E getSingleResultWithParam(Class<E> eClass, Class<T> tClass, X... param) {
        try {
            CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<E> queryFilter = builder.createQuery(eClass);
            Root<E> root = queryFilter.from(eClass);
            queryFilter.select(root);

            List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i <= param.length / 2; i += 2) {
                predicateList.add(builder.equal(root.get((String) param[i]).as(tClass), param[i + 1]));
            }

            Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[predicateList.size()];
            predicateList.toArray(predicates);
            queryFilter.where(predicates);

            return (E) getSingleResultOrNull(entityManager.createQuery(queryFilter));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(DEF_ERROR_MSG, e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

метод динамический но все же хочется знать правильно ли через такой метод обращение в базу?

Comment: Правильно. Какие сомнения?

Comment: Лучше из таких низкоуровневых методов исключения выбрасывать, а не логировать.